# How to derive Lorentz (general) transformation in Special Relativity?

Tags: linear-algebra, semi-riemannian-geometry, special-relativity

Let $M$ be a 4-vector space over $\mathbb R$. Since $M$ is linearly isomorphic to $\mathbb R^4$, the linear isomorphism is also a diffeomorphism between $M$ and $\mathbb R^4$.
For each $p\in M$, we define a **Minkowski metric tensor** on $T_pM$ is a bilinear, symmetric and non-degenerate form $\,\langle,\rangle_p:\ T_pM\times T_pM\longrightarrow\mathbb R\, $ with signature $(+,+,+,-)$. The space $\big(M,\langle,\rangle\big)$ then is called **Minkowski space**.

> Lemma 1.   There exists an orthonormal basis for $T_pM\ $ (orthonormal with respect to $\langle,\rangle_p$).
> Lemma 2.  For any basis $\mathcal B=(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4)$ of $T_pM$,
> \begin{align}
> \langle u,v\rangle_p\,=\,\big[u\big]^\top_{\mathcal B}\,\langle,\rangle_{p\mathcal B} \,\big[v\big]_{\mathcal B},\ \forall\,u,v\in T_pM.
> \end{align}
> where $\,\langle,\rangle_{p\mathcal B}=\big(\langle e_i,e_j\rangle\big)_{ij}$.
> Thus, we have an orthonormal basis of $T_pM$ in which our Minkowski metric tensor has the form
> \begin{align}
> \langle u,v\rangle_p\,=\,u_1v_1+u_2v_2+u_3v_3-u_4v_4,\ \forall\,u,v\in T_pM.\tag1
> \end{align}

Let $\eta=$ diag$(I_3,-1)$. A **Lorentz transformation** is a linear map $\,T:\,\mathbb R^4\longrightarrow\mathbb R^4\,$ satisfies
\begin{align}
\big[T\big]^\top\eta\big[T\big]\,=\,\eta.
\end{align}
It is the transformation that preserves the Minkowski structure of $M$.
More specifically, the matrix of each Lorentz transformation is given by
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\ y_2\\ y_3 \\ ct'
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
1+(\gamma-1)\displaystyle\frac{v_1^2}{v^2}  &  (\gamma-1)\displaystyle\frac{v_1v_2}{v^2}  &  (\gamma-1)\displaystyle\frac{v_1v_3}{v^2}  &  -\displaystyle\frac{\gamma v_1}{c}
\\ (\gamma-1)\displaystyle\frac{v_1v_2}{v^2}  &  1+(\gamma-1)\displaystyle\frac{v_2^2}{v^2}  &  (\gamma-1)\displaystyle\frac{v_2v_3}{v^2}  &  -\displaystyle\frac{\gamma v_2}{c}
\\ (\gamma-1)\displaystyle\frac{v_1v_3}{v^2}  &  (\gamma-1)\displaystyle\frac{v_2v_3}{v^2}  &  1+(\gamma-1)\displaystyle\frac{v_3^2}{v^2}  &  \displaystyle\frac{\gamma v_3}{c}
\\  -\displaystyle\frac{\gamma v_1}{c}  &  -\displaystyle\frac{\gamma v_2}{c}  &  -\displaystyle\frac{\gamma v_3}{c}  &  \gamma  
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\ x_2\\ x_3 \\ ct
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
c=1,\ \ \ \gamma=\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}^{-1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}},\ \ \ v^2=\|v\|^2=\sqrt{v_1^2+v_2^2+v_3^2}.
\end{align*}

I found some solution for obtaining the Lorentz transformation with physics and geometry approach. My question is how can one derrive the formula for the Lorentz transformation $T$ with linear algebra approach ? Apparently, we can solve this matrix equation in term of linear system equation, but I wonder if there is other ways better ?

I hope someone will help me with some hints for this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you keep saying *the* Lorentz transformation? There are, I would guess, 6 parameters in the space of Lorentz transformation.

Comment: I still yet to get your mean

Comment: What Ted is saying is that your question is meaningless as stated.

Comment: @MoisheKohan what should I do ?

Comment: Using linear algebra you can reduce any special orthogonal matrix to block diagonal form, which shows the matrix as a composition of rotations in planes. The indefinite signature of the Minkowski metric doesn't change the details much from the standard inner product space procedure.

Comment: @ziggurism when we consider the 2 dimension case which is associated with a Lorentz boost in a axis-direction, for instance, $x$-direction, we can use diagonalizable matrix to derive the Lorentz transformation

Comment: @ziggurism suppose $T$ is a  Lorentz boost in $x$-direction. Consider the vector $(x,t)=(1,1)$, this is a lightlike vector. By Einstein postulate on speed of light, $T(1,1)$ is also a lightlike vector, and hence belongs to a light cone, this implies $T(1,1)=\lambda(1,1)$. Analogously, we also have $T(1,-1)=\mu (1,-1)$. Therefore, $(1,1),\ (-1,1)$ are eigenvectors of $T$. Since thesse vectors are a basis of $\mathbb R^2$, $T$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: @ziggurism From here, one can derive the formula of Lorentz boostz as 
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
t'\\ y_1\\ y_2\\ y_3
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
\gamma& -\gamma v&0& 0 \\ -\gamma v&\gamma&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
t\\ x_1\\ x_2\\ x_3
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
where $\gamma=\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}$.

Comment: @ziggurism but I wonder if we can do it the same way for the general Lorentz transformation in arbitrary direction, since I can't find any eigenvector for the transformation in this case

Comment: Light-cone coordinates diagonalize the spatial-time-like pairs of coordinates, and complex basis like $x+iy$ diagonalizes the spatial-spatial pairs. Moving back to standard real $(d-1,1)$ signature basis, the matrix is block diagonalized and each spatial-spatial block is a rotation and each spatial-timelike pair is a boost.

Comment: I've been thinking about it a bit more, and I think if your proper Lorentz transformation is neither a pure boost nor a pure rotation, then the relationship between the boost vector and the rotation parameters and the eigenvectors will not be straightforward. I think you should start off with assuming pure boost/pure rotation.

Comment: even asking the analogous question for orthogonal transformations of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with positive definite inner product is a little tricky. What would it mean to "derive the explicit formula for the transformation" in this case? Personally I would take that to mean, given an $3\times 3$ special orthogonal matrix, find the three Euler angles. the formulas for that are kind of ugly and heavy with algebra and trig (but it can be done).

Comment: The nicer way to write it is using Lie algebra coordinates: $R(\theta)=\exp{(\theta\mathbf{\hat{n}}\cdot\mathbf{J})}$ where $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ is the unit vector of the axis of rotation (the eigenvalue), $\theta$ is the magnitude, and $\mathbf{J}$ is the generators.

Comment: Similarly for a proper Lorentz transformation, it can be written $\Lambda(\zeta,\theta)=\exp{(\mathbf{\theta}\cdot\mathbf{J} + \mathbf{\zeta}\cdot \mathbf{K})}.$

Comment: But note that unless the boost direction is orthogonal to all the rotation planes, then the boost operator and rotation operator do not commute, and while we can write the Lorentz transformation as a product of a boost and a rotation, the values of those operations will not be related to the $\mathbf{\theta},\mathbf{\zeta}$ parameters. The relation will be given by the Baker-Hausdorff-Campbell formula, which is an infinite series. The eigenvectors of the combined transformation will not be the eigenvectors of the rotation and the boost.

Comment: But for a pure boost, the eigenvectors will be the light-cone coordinates of the boost direction and the timelike coordinate, and the eigenvalue will be the boost parameter $\gamma$. And for a pure rotation, the eigenvectors will be complexified combinations of the vectors spanning the plane of rotation, and the eigenvalues will be (trig functions of) the angle of rotation. So the linear algebra works out nicely for those special cases.

Comment: @ziggurism I edited my post.

Comment: @ziggurism thank you alot, your answer is really helpful to me

Comment: @ziggurism i created a new post of this topic [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4856313/the-group-so1-3-and-its-lie-algebra/4856378#4856378), I hope you will check it out and explain a little bit more about the approach using Lie algebra coordinates that you hinted above