# The group $SO(1,3)$ and its Lie algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, special-relativity

Denote the matrix $\eta=$ diag$(-1,1,1,1)$. The group $O(1,3)$, called *Lorentz group*, is the group of all matrix $L\in M_4(\mathbb R)$ such that
\begin{align}
L^\top\eta\,L\,=\,\eta.\tag1
\end{align}
The subgroup of all Lorentz matrix in $O(1,3)$ of determinant 1 is denoted as $SO(1,3)$. My aim is to find the explicit description of each matrix $L\in SO(1,3)$.

Since $O(1,3)$ and $SO(1,3)$ is a Lie group, they admits a Lie algebra. Indeed, at the present I have not so much understand of the formal definition of the Lie algebra of a Lie group. However, in this concrete context, I know that the Lie algebra of $SO(1,3)$ is given by
\begin{align}
\mathfrak{so}(1,3)\,=\,\Big\{X\in M_4(\mathbb R)\,\big|\,e^{tX}\in SO(1,3)\ \, \forall t\in\mathbb R\Big\}.\tag2
\end{align}
By the definition of exponential matrix, for any $X\in \mathfrak{so}(1,3)$, $\exists A\in M_4(\mathbb R)$ such that
\begin{align}
e^{tX}\,=\,I_4+A.\tag3
\end{align}
Since $e^{tX}\in SO(1,3)$, we have
\begin{align}
\eta\,&=\,(I_4+A)^\top\eta\, (I_4+A)
\\ &=\,\eta+\eta A+A^\top\eta+A^\top\eta\,A\tag4
\end{align}
Omitting the term $A^\top\eta\,A$, we obtain
\begin{align}
(\eta A)^\top\,=\,-\eta A.\tag5
\end{align}
We can deduce that, then, $A$ is given by
\begin{align}
A\,=\,\begin{bmatrix}
0&a&b&c
\\ a&0&d&e
\\ b&-d&0&f
\\ c&-e&-f&0
\end{bmatrix},\ a,b,c,d,e,f\in\mathbb R.\tag6
\end{align}
This implies
\begin{align}
A\,&=\,\theta_1J_1+\theta_2J_2+\theta_3J_3+\lambda_1K_1+\lambda_2K_2+\lambda_3K_3
\\ &=\,\theta\cdot J+\lambda\cdot K\tag7
\end{align}
where $\theta=\big(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3\big),\,\lambda=\big(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3\big)\in\mathbb R^3$ and
\begin{align}
J_1=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0
\\ 0&0&0&-1
\\ 0&0&1&0
\end{pmatrix}\ \ \ J_2=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&0 
\\ 0&0&0&1 \\ 0&0&0&0
\\ 0&-1&0&0
\end{pmatrix}\ \ \ J_3=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&0 
\\ 0&0&-1&0 \\ 0&1&0&0
\\ 0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}\tag8
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
K_1=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0&0 \\ 1&0&0&0
\\ 0&0&0&0
\\ 0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}\ \ \ K_2=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1&0 
\\ 0&0&0&0 \\ 1&0&0&0
\\ 0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}\ \ \ K_3=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&1 
\\ 0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0
\\ 1&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}.\tag8
\end{align}
These matrices satisfy (5).

By direct calculating, we can show that
\begin{align}
\big[J_i,J_j\big]\,&=\,\varepsilon_{ijk}J_k
\\ \big[J_i,K_j\big]\,&=\,\varepsilon_{ijk}K_k
\\ \big[K_i,K_j\big]\,&=\,-\varepsilon_{ijk}J_k\tag{10}
\end{align}
where the coefficients $\varepsilon_{ijk}$ are the Levi-Cevita symbol and the commutator $\big[J_i,K_j\big]=J_iK_j-K_jJ_i$.

Substituting (7) into (3), we get
\begin{align}
e^{tX}\,=\,I_4+\sum_1^3\theta_i J_i+\sum_1^3\lambda_i K_i\,=\,\begin{bmatrix}
1&\lambda_1&\lambda_2&\lambda_3
\\ \lambda_1&1&-\theta_3&\theta_2
\\ \lambda_2&\theta_3&1&-\theta_1
\\ \lambda_3&-\theta_2&\theta_1&1
\end{bmatrix}.\tag{11}
\end{align}
Finally, any Lorentz matrix of $SO(1,3)$ is given by
\begin{align}
L\,=\,e^{\theta\cdot J+\lambda\cdot K}\tag{12}
\end{align}
for arbitrary $\theta,\lambda\in\mathbb R^3 $.

In this solution, there're some move that I still yet to understand.

1/ Why could we neglect the term $A^\top\eta\,A$ in (5) ?

2/ Why do we need to consider the commutator in (10), what is its role in the proof ?

3/ How can one get the result at (12) from the preceding moves ?

I hope someone would help me to clarify those impedents. Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that $SO(1,3)$ is not connected?

Comment: @MoisheKohan yes, I know that $SO(1,3)$ has two connected component, corresponding to the time orientation of the Minkowski space.

Comment: Then how come you claim that the exponential map is surjective in equation (12)?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I found in some material a theorem states that the exponential map is surjective, however the author didn't provide a proof.

Comment: Well, do you see that the author was wrong? The exponential map is onto the identity component of the Lorentz group.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I get what you meant. So I should consider the subgroup $SO^+(1,3)$ instead of $SO(1,3)$, then since $SO^+(1,3)$  is connected, the exponential map will be surjective on this space, right ?

Comment: Surjectivity does not always follow from connectedness but in this case one proves surjectivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. That argument is a little handwavy and I suspect the answer is: $A$ is "small enough". A better proof is to just differentiate $\exp(tX)^T\eta\exp(tX) = \eta$ by product rule which yields:
   $$ \frac{d}{dt}\exp(tX)^T\eta\exp(tX) = X^T\eta\exp(tX) + \exp(tX)^T\eta X = 0$$
   and thus
   $$ \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\exp(tX)^T\eta\exp(tX) = X^T\eta + \eta X = 0$$
   I'm not the hugest fan of using the transpose here though if I'm honest. For orthogonal transformations, transpose is the same as inverse but that is not true for the Lorentz group and I think that leads to misunderstandings down the line. The transpose  really assumes you've picked a basis or more directly a definite inner product. I'd much rather just say that the elements of the group preserve the indefinite symmetric bilinear form and that differentiating gives you elements of the Lie algebra as skew for the same bilinear form by the same product rule style argument.
2. Lie algebras have a Lie bracket. That's what makes them Lie algebras. The commutator is the standard example of a Lie bracket. And indeed by Ado's Theorem any Lie bracket (on a finite dimensional Lie algebra) can be described as the commutator by taking some faithful representation of the Lie algebra. So in your case this is just realising $\mathfrak{so}(3,1)$ in its representation on $\mathbb{R}^{3,1}$
3. This is just not true as Moishe pointed out in the comments. $SO(3,1)$ is not connected so the exponential map cannot be surjective here. It is, however, surjective onto the connected component of the identity in this case. In physics that subgroup is often denoted $SO^+(3,1)$ and called the set of orthochronous Lorentz transformations.
4. I don't really know what is going into the matrix if I'm perfectly honest. It does seem to have only 3 parameters in it which wouldn't really make sense as the group is 6-dimensional but maybe those are complex numbers or I'm missing something else.

Comment: regarding (4), that formula gives the *“boost along $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$”*. OP is confused because physicists often call this a “general Lorentz transformation”, when in fact it is only a general “boost”. Roughly speaking, the missing $6-3=3$ parameters are recovered once we note that we can further rotate the 3 spatial axes. I’ve actually never seen a fully general formula (though I’ve never had a need for it either).

Comment: @peek-a-boo so there is difference between "transformation" and "boost" ? Anyway, in [this article](http://physics.unm.edu/Courses/Finley/p581/Handouts/CompleteLorentzGroup.pdf) the author deduced the general boost on page 23 (3.12)

Comment: @PermQi a Lorentz boost is a special type of Lorentz transformation. What I mean in my previous comment is that I haven’t seen a general explicit formula for all Lorentz transformations (the formula for *boosts* is standard and appears in all SR texts, and as you said, in your link).

Comment: @peek-a-boo may you provide a formal definition for a Lorentz transformation ? Is it a linear map whose matrix is satisfied by equation (1) or is it something different ?

Comment: @PermQi yes that’s it.

Comment: @peek-a-boo and a general Lorentz boost in arbitrary direction that I usually refer is the element of the orthochronous Lorentz subgroup $SO^+(1,3)$, right ?

Comment: @PermQi a "general Lorentz boost" refers to one type of element in $SO^+(3,1)$yes. Together with rotations, they generate the whole of $SO^+(3,1)$ Then you need to add in antichronous transformations to get $SO(3,1)$ (and reflections if you want all of $O(3,1)$)

Comment: @Callum you mean the general Lorentz boosts still not all elements of $SO^+(1,3) $ ? So what is the subgroup of all general Lorentz boosts ?

Comment: @PermQi they do not form a subgroup. The product of two boosts is not necessarily a boost.

Comment: @Callum wait, as I understand, a "boost" is a Lorentz transformation that represents an orthogonal 3d spatial coordinate system that uniformly rectilinear moving respect to time, right ?

Comment: @Callum okay I think I get the point here. So, basically, a "boosts" is just a 3d uniform rectilinear translation, and an element of $SO^+(1,3)$ is the composition of a spatial rotation with such a translation, right ?

Comment: @PermQi You'd have to ask a Physicist if that is the correct interpretation but the last part is correct: an element of $SO^+(3,1)$ is a combination of a boost and a rotation.

Comment: @Callum in the wikipedia, I find a statement "In theoretical physics, the composition of two non-collinear Lorentz boosts results in a Lorentz transformation that is not a pure boost but is the composition of a boost and a rotation. This rotation is called Thomas rotation, Thomas–Wigner rotation or Wigner rotation."  So by this definition, is every element of $SO^+(1,3)$ a Wigner rotation ?

Comment: @PermQi No the Wigner rotation is the resulting **rotation** of applying two non-collinear boosts not the name for whole resulting element.

Comment: @peek-a-boo from (7), and by using the fact that every $L\in SO^+(1,3)$ satisfies $L=e^A$ for some $A\in\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$, when $\theta=0$, we obtain the Lorentz boost in arbitrary direction $v$
$$L=e^{v\cdot K}$$
But I have no idea how to imply the form 
$$L=e^{\psi(\widehat v\cdot K)} $$
where $\tanh\psi=|v| $. May you help me to explain that ?